# Can not seem to use a base64 string from a file for a variable in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm having an issue parsing a base64 string from a text file in to a batch variable

I have a script that is generating a config for an application in XML using batch, I have the XML generating fine. The problem is, within the XML I generate is some base64 that encodes more XML with variables that I need to modify. Headache and a half. (The application in question requires this or it breaks the config)

I have the XML that needs to be encoded in to a base64 string in a text file but I need to load that text file into a variable but I think the string is breaking the variable.

The base64 it has generated is this:

```
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
```

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (%~dp0\base.txt) do (
set base=%%c
)
echo %base%
```

I'm using the above for loop to load the file into a variable, but when echoing I get no output as it doesn't seem to have set the variable for some reason. Other text files I've loaded in to a variable using this method work.

Comment: My apologies actually the base64 I supplied was incorrect. I've supplied correct base64 and the amount of characters is within the limitation? Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If the file is one line, why not simply use `set /p base=<"%~dp0\base.txt"`

Comment: Doing
```
set /p base=<"%~dp0base.txt"
echo %base%
pause
```
Gives me echo 
```
P
P
```
Doing
``` 
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%c in ("%~dp0base.txt") do set "base=%%c"
echo %base%
pause
```
gives me echo is on.

I'm feeling stupid here :/
I'm using windows server 2012 for this, not XP

Also thanks for the time to help me

Comment: I just think I found the problem, it's with encoding. On generation of the base64 its encoding it in UCS-2 LE BOM for some reason. I guess I have to ensure its encoding in ANSI as if I switch the encoding it works!

Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR -

Is this a pre-WinXp system?

Details:

Is that a long base64, or are you happy to see me?  :-)

First I wondered about the line's length.  But any WinXp+ will handle 8k chars, so the 7,664 in your example shouldn't be an issue.

So I wondered about plus signs and back slashes outside double-quotes.  However, the lack of dbl-quotes wasn't an issue in my testing.  This worked just fine:

```
--CMD:--
for /f %A in (c:\temp\z.txt) do @set zLongTmp=%A
--OUTPUT:--
...a 7,664 char output...
```

So I checked the string, and found only [A-Z0-9+/]....so nothing out of the ordinary

I've done other tests, but all succeeded.  I'm left wondering if this is a pre-WinXp system, that has a cmdline max of 2047 characters.  And if that's not it, I'd still advise using Double quotes around the 'set' command.

Example:

```
for /f %A in (c:\temp\z.txt) do @set "zLongTmp=%A"
echo %A
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here I was having was the file I was trying to load as a variable was encoded in UCS-2 LE BOM. I had to ensure the file was encoded in UTF 8 Without BOM and all worked as required.

Thanks to everyone who helped figure this out.